# confusion over assigning value to "undefined", using IIFE with "undefined" as parameter

Tags: javascript, function, undefined, iife

I'm currently studying javascript by following the book series "you dont know js".

In the book, section "scope & closure", where the author is discussing "IIFE", the author mentioned

> Another application of this pattern addresses the (minor niche)
>   concern that the default undefined identifier might have its value
>   incorrectly overwritten, causing unexpected results. By naming a
>   parameter undefined, but not passing any value for that argument, we
>   can guarantee that the undefined identifier is in fact the undefined
>   value in a block of code:
>
> ```
> undefined = true; // setting a land-mine for other code! avoid!
>
> (function IIFE( undefined ){
>
>   var a;
>   if (a === undefined) {
>       console.log( "Undefined is safe here!" );
>   }
>
> })();
> ```

But I thought `undefined` is a non-writable variable. And when I tried `undefined = true;` in chrome browser, the value of `undefined` indeed did not change (i.e. the assignment failed silently under non-strict mode). So why is the author trying to assign to `undefined` ?

And secondly, I'm not really sure what is the purpose of `IIFE` function with `undefined` as its parameter? Like what are some of the potential uses?

Comment: *"So why is the author trying to assign to `undefined` ?"* `undefined` wasn't always read-only. Back in the day to avoid breakage of your code because somebody messed with `undefined`, you would simply create your "own version".

Comment: This changed in a later ES version - there are *legacy questions* that deal with it. ES3 has not such guarantees - not sure if it was ES5 or ES6 that "corrected" the situation.

Comment: also you can set a variable to the name undefined as well, which if you have a certain scope of things could ruin everything.

Comment: Your second question is answered by the quote you pasted: "*By naming a parameter `undefined`, but not passing any value for that argument, we can guarantee that the `undefined` identifier is in fact the undefined value in a block of code*"

Comment: @FelixKling ah, ok, so `undefined` used to be writable, but now its just a read only property. Make sense

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined says: "*In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), `undefined` is a non-configurable, non-writable property per the ECMAScript 5 specification.*" So apparently before ES5 `undefined` was writable.

Comment: Also you don't really know in which browsers your code runs. Not that I think these days people run browsers that are that old, but ES5 took a while to be adopted.

Comment: @melpomene I understand why the author came up with IIFE with `undefined` as a parameter, but I guess what I was trying to ask is: what are some of the practical useage for such thing?